# Expression for $\exp\left(x\right) -1$

Tags: exponential-function

Found an unexpected expression:
$$e^x -1=xe^{\theta.x}$$
where $\theta \in \left(0,1\right)$.
However, I cannot prove it (the $\theta$ part).
Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Try the mean value theorem on $f(x) = e^x$. $f(x) = f(0) + f'(\xi) x$.

Comment: Can not prove what? That isn't  always true. the the expression can not be proven because it is not true.  I think you are supposed to *solve* for $x$ for values where it is true for a constant $\theta$.

Comment: What does it mean "prove the $\theta$ part"? Why your expression is "unexpected"?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you greatly to everybody for your help. Mean Value Theorem works:

**Fix x** and consider the function $f(y)=\exp \left(xy\right)$ on the interval $y \in \left(0, 1\right)$. The function $f\left(y\right)$ is differentiable on this interval with respect to $y$. Then, by the MVT, there exists $\theta \in \left(0, 1\right)$ such that $$x \exp \left(x \theta\right)=\exp \left(x\right)-1.$$
Done.

Comment: So then your question was something like: For all $x$ show there exists $\theta$ such that $e^x-1=xe^{\theta x}$? Cause that was not clear to me from the way you phrased this question.

Comment: To be honest, I think you have the question backwards.  What you have shown is that for any fixed $x$ there will a value of $\theta$ where the equation holds for the fixed $x$.  I think what the question is *actually* asking is to prove for  a fixed $\theta$ that there exist an $x$ where the equation is true.  (It's very similar)